# Is there a way to share the bank in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I started to play recently and I created a new character and had a surprise that the bank is not the same for the new character.

How can I pass my items or have a shared bank with my other character in the same realm? I don't have anyone ingame I could trust to give them the items so they could give it back to the other character.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While there is no way to share personal bank space between characters, there are a couple ways to pass items around:

1. You can mail the items between your characters. Items mailed to characters on the same account will appear in the other character's inbox immediately.
2. Get some guild signatures and become your own guild. You can then use the guild bank on all your characters instead of the normal personal bank.

I recommend going with option #1 so you can join a real guild and enjoy that part of the game too.

Comment: Start a Guild with your alts and have those manage your 'spare' bank. Especially the first slots are relatively cheap.

Comment: @Ivo Unless you do some heavy crafting, that's overkill, especially for a new player.

Comment: Just to add to this, some items can become "soul bound".  Once an item is soulbound it can only be sold to a vendor or destroyed.  The 3 main types of bindings are: Bind on Equip (BoE), Bind on Pickup (BoP), and Bind on Account (BoA).